# Possible xcode 4.2 bug

Tags: ios, xcode

This may be because I am just unfamiliar with xcode as I am just starting out.  I have been reading through some tutorials and playing around with some options in xcode, and I noticed that if I am viewing my storyboard file and change from standard editor to version editor, the storyboard file reverts to its xml code.  When I go back to the standard editor, the xml code remains, and I can not for the life of me figure out how to change it back to the graphical editor.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-click on the storyboard file in the Project Navigator (left side) and select "Open As..." -> "Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard". Definitely a bug in Xcode.

I suggest filing a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com